# How to append queried objects from Django database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a model with 2 fields for numbers. I am trying to query those numbers and append them to each others. How do I do that? How do I work with queried objects?

This is Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    num2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('diary:post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

This is view (here I am trying to query and work with queried objects)

```
def home(request):
    a = Post.objects.values('num1')
    b = Post.objects.values('num2')
    result = a + b 
    context = {
        'result': result,
        }
    
    return render(request, 'diary/home.html', context)
```

This is a working part of my template

```
{% for x in result %}
    
   
    <p> {{ x }} </p>

{% endfor %}
```

This is the error I get

```
TypeError at /
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'

C:\Users\detal\Coding\Trading Diary3\TradingDiary\diary\views.py, line 11, in home
    result = a + b
```

Comment: What is the type of `a` and `b`? It seems you are assuming them to be numbers. But are they really numbers ? The error message suggests they are 'QuerySet' type.

Comment: Yeah, them are queries. My question is how do I work with query type objects? I have multiple num1 and num2 in the database (both belong to one model) and I want to append num1 and num2 together and assign the resulted value to a new object (doesn't matter if it just give the value immediately or stores it in the database). Any solution is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Here's my view code:

```
def home(request):
    x = Post.objects.all().values_list("num1","num2")
    array = []
    for i in x:
        y = i[0] + i[1]
        array.append(y)  

   
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
        'array':array,
        }
    
    return render(request, 'diary/home.html', context)
```

and template code:

```
{% for i in array %}
    <p> {{ i }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

The output is the list of appended numbers of num1 and num2. There was also problem for me while solving - you don't need to "return" the for loop result in views. It works only without it

Answer (score 0):

The return of your query will be dictionary. To add both query's you can try

```
result = q.union(b)
```

for a much more cleaner look

```
records = query1 | query2
```

If you don't want duplicates, then add .distinct()

```
records = (query1 | query2).distinct()
```

if you want specific field only you can try

```
Post.objects.all().values_list(
"num2").union(Post1.objects.all().values_list("num1"))
```

or if it is from same table

```
Post1.objects.all().values_list("num1","num2"))
```